# HTML div height attribute is not working

Tags: html, css

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4yXb/4/

In HTML, I have a header, and a button on the header. I would like to have them both with the same height, so that they align correctly.

I am using the `height` attribute on the header div in css, and I am using a percentage so it is responsive based on screen size.

In the fiddle, you can see that the `.header-button` is not the same height as the `.header`, even though it has the same `height` attribute as the `.header`.

How do I get these elements to align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the height in percentages, the height is always dependent on the parent element. So if the parent element is 50% high and the child element is also 50% high, it will be 50% of the height of the parent. So if the parent is 50px high, the child will be 25px high. That's one reason it isn't working. Then things like padding and border are *added* to the height, so in my example, the 25px high child element with 5px padding and 2px border will end up being 39px high.

To make up for the additional height of the child element (.header-menu), give the parent element (.header) the same additional padding and border, and change the height of the child element back to 100%:

```
.header {
    padding-bottom: 31px;
    border-bottom: 6px #808080 solid;
}
.header-menu {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/w4yXb/15/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much, and I chose the answer.

Comment: Your solution works, but the rules for [calculating height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) are a bit more complicated.

Comment: The question wasn't about explaining all the rules of how to calculate height. The question was, how to get two specific elements to have the same height.